# Issue in join query of multiple tables sqlite

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, left-join

hello friends i have four tables as below

```
property_master --> "p_id" , "p_name" , "p_address" , "p_city" , "p_state" ,"r_id"

property_unit -->"unit_id"   , "p_id"  , "unit_name"   ,"r_id"

unit_info -->    "unit_info_id"   ,"unit_id" INTEGER,"p_id"   ,"p_bathroom"  ,"p_bedroom"  ,"p_size"  ,"p_rent"  ,"p_isrent"  ,"u_note" ,"r_id" 

tanant_master -->  "t_id"   , "t_name"  ,"t_cell_no"  ,"t_phone_no"  ,"t_mail"  ,"t_deposit"   ,"r_id"

property_assign-->  "t_assign_id"   , "unit_info_id"  ,  "t_id"  , "t_start_date"  , "t_end_date"  , "  t_rent_due_day"  , "t_lease_alert"  , "t_status"  ,"r_id"
```

and my query is as below

```
Select p_name As "Property",
p_id AS "PID",
(Select Count(unit_id) from property_unit where   property_master.p_id=property_unit.p_id )As "UnitCount",
(Select Count(unit_info_id) from unit_info where unit_info.unit_info_id=property_assign.unit_info_id )As "TenantCount"
From property_master  ,property_assign Group by property_master.p_id
```

i need total tenant count propertywise but when i run above query it gives me only first property tenant count for all property any idea how can i solve it?

Comment: Could you provide simple data for tables and desired result example? Also it is strange, that you do Cartesian join of  property_master and property_assign (join without providing any conditions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select a.PID,
       MAX(a.Property) as "Property",
       COUNT(a.unit_id) as "UnitCount",
       SUM(a.TenantCount) as "TenantCount"
  from (
        select property_master.p_id as "PID",
               MAX(property_master.p_name) as  "Property",
               property_unit.unit_id,
               COUNT(property_assign.t_id) as "TenantCount"
          from property_master
          JOIN property_unit ON property_master.p_id = property_unit.p_id
          JOIN unit_info ON unit_info.unit_id = property_unit.unit_id
          JOIN property_assign ON unit_info.unit_info_id = property_assign.unit_info_id 
         group by property_master.p_id, property_unit.unit_id
       ) a,
 group by a.PID
```

**Note 1** You probably need to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `JOIN` depends on your data structure (can be `property_assign` empty or not?)

**Note 2.** Sorry, I couldn't test it. You should do it yourself.

Comment: MyDogTom you query gave me syntax error near **group by**

Comment: @user3547706 Strange. I tested a similar query on mine tables and it works. Which one `group by` gives you an error? Try to execute only inner query. Is it works? Check, that all names a correct.

Comment: MyDogTom  you make a join with **property_unit.unit_info _id** but in **property_unit** there are no any such fields like **unit_info_id**

Comment: @user3547706 I see. So you have to add one more join with `unit_info` to link `property_unit` and `property_assign`. I updated answer. Take a look. In fact I tried to show you main idea.